# How to pass password on stdin to psql and other utilities?

Tags: postgresql

One can accomplish passing the password by specifying in ~/.pgpass. I am however curious if there is a way to do so with stdin without using something like `expect`. The following does not appear to work:

```
psql -U postgres <<< "mypw"
```

Comment: I don't know the particulars of psql but the reason it doesn't work for a lot of programs is that they don't read the password from `stdin`, they actually open the file `/dev/tty` and read the password from there.  `/dev/tty` is connected to the "controlling terminal"  by whatever system is managing your keyboard and display (for example, X) through the magic of pseudo-terminals.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could set an [environment variable PGPASSWORD](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html).